# How to display the version of glusterfs?

Tags: glusterfs

I didn't find any information on how to display the version of my glusterfs client and server. I think it should be easy. I have tried "gluster version", it cannot work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
glusterfs --version
```

and

```
glusterd --version
```